# How did the nucleus of eukaryotic cells evolve?

Tags: evolution, eukaryotic-cells

What is/are the most popular theory/theories on how the nucleus evolved?
I know mitochondria came from alpha-proteobacteria, chloroplasts from cyanobacteria and that eukaryotes evolved directly from archaea, but what about the nucleus?

Comment: [Devos et al. 2014](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0955067414000052) will be of interest as well as [wikipedia > Nucleus#evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_nucleus#Evolution).

Answer (score -1):

I hope these papers by [Wilson and Dawson (2011)](http://jcb.rupress.org/content/195/2/171.full?sid=9d01561a-67d4-41b2-9dd4-4585c1494206) and [Devos et al. (2014)](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0955067414000052/1-s2.0-S0955067414000052-main.pdf?_tid=decc9e27-a4a3-4bfa-9a46-eb3baa02da69&acdnat=1521532493_a1baa8412e833e34827fd98833000d81) will help you.

In summary these two review provide evidence for the following statements:

1. The nuclear pore complex is well conserved with some regions of divergence.
2. The nuclear lamina appears quite variable between major supergroups.
3. Centrosomes are ancient structures but exhibit a complex evolutionary history.
4. There is evidence for prokaryotic ancestors of some nuclear components.
5. Analysis of divergent organisms is essential to fully understand nuclear biology and its origins.

Comment: But this is not an answer to the question. The poster is clearly asking for theories on the origin of the nucleus (he makes comparison with the origin of mitochondria) but your ‘summary’ of the papers does no more than say “there is evidence fro prokaryotic ancestors of some nuclear components”. Answers need to be self-contained and provide information in response to the question.